# rosrun : Package not found

Tags: ros, rospy

How to run a python script file for ros ?

I have developed python script to make a drone to fly. I have kept the code inside

**tumsimulator/src/scripts/DroneFly.py.  ## catkin make is done in this directory
When I run the code in tumsimulator directory, it throws an error saying that scripts directory is not found.**

I gave chmod 777 permission for directory as well as the file.

Can Somebody help me to run the python script in ros ?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf can you help me in this ?

Comment: Could you post your `CMakeLists.txt` file as well as your file structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be on the same page

1. you need to create a catkin workspace a catkin package. For example you create a workspace called `catkin_ws`

   ```
   mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
   cd ~/catkin_ws/src
   catkin_init_workspace
   ```
2. Create your package called `tumsimulator` in `~/home/catkin_ws/src`

   ```
   catkin_create_pkg tumsimulator rospy
   ```
3. Put the `scripts` directory in `tumsimulator/` not in `tumsimulator/src`. Once after running catkin_make, you should be able to run the script via
4. Run catkin_make

   ```
   cd ~/catkin_ws
   catkin_make
   ```
5. Finally, run your script

   ```
   rosrun tumsimulator DroneFly.py
   ```

As a side note, scripts should note have the py extension. You can add the python shebang line at the top of your script file `#! /usr/bin/env python`. If your are writing a python module, you may put these files in `tumsimulator/src/tumsimulator/` next to `tumsimulator/src/tumsimulator/__init__.py`.

Comment: Hi, I tried to follow this 
https://github.com/dougvk/tum_simulator

so, from the above instructions, in which directory should I have clone the ardrone autonomy ?

Comment: I guess what you want to do is put them in `~/tum_simulator/src/tum_simulator/scripts` then after running `cd ~/tum_simulator && catkin_make` you can start the script via `rosrun tum_simulator DroneFly.py`. Note the underscore in `tum_simulator`!

Comment: after catkin make # no error in python file, I ran this command 
roslaunch cvg_sim_gazebo ardrone_testworld.launch but it doesnot launch gazebo simulator....any clue to fix this ?

Comment: Hi...if you can make a video of the whole process till the file execution , it 'll be very helpful

Comment: @Kathir I believe this is a different issue. This issue was about the python script. Please close this one and post a new one for the Gazebo issue with the exact error you are getting. Thanks